# UITableView Checkmark not appearing when selected

Tags: ios

I am using a UITableView on button click i am putting the tableview into edit mode I have added

> tableView.allowMultiselectionduringedit = true

Here i am getting circles to select the table but no check mark is added when tapped. But code in didselectrow is getting executed

I have attached a picture
[image]

What should i change to get the rows selected

Code for didselect

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Did select Run")
    if(isEditing){
        let cell = chatTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.setSelected(true, animated: true)

    }else{
        let groupMsg = groupMsgList[indexPath.row]
        if(groupMsg.messageType == "file")
        {
            let fileNameString = groupMsg.fileOriginalName
            if(fileNameString != nil){
                let fileName: NSString = fileNameString! as NSString
                let extention = fileName.pathExtension.lowercased()
                switch extention {
                case "jpg","png","jpeg":
                    if (groupMsg.senderUserId != LoginStatusInfo.userId){
                        let row = chatTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! PhotoReciveCell
                        chatTableView.beginUpdates()
                        row.downloadLabel.text = " Downloading... "
                        row.downloadLabel.sizeToFit()
                        row.downloadLabelConstraint.constant = 30.0
                        row.downloadLabel.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2.0, left: 2.0, bottom: 2.0, right: 2.0)
                        downloadFileBackground(id: groupMsg.messageId!, fileName: groupMsg.message!, cellIndexPath: indexPath )
                        chatTableView.endUpdates()
                    }else{
                        let row = chatTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! PhotoSentCell
                        chatTableView.beginUpdates()
                        row.downloadLabel.text = " Downloading... "
                        row.downloadLabel.sizeToFit()
                        row.downloadLabelConstraint.constant = 30.0
                        row.downloadLabel.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2.0, left: 2.0, bottom: 2.0, right: 2.0)
                        downloadFileBackground(id: groupMsg.messageId!, fileName: groupMsg.message!, cellIndexPath: indexPath )
                        chatTableView.endUpdates()
                    }
                    break
                default :
                    if (groupMsg.senderUserId != LoginStatusInfo.userId){
                        let row = chatTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FileRecieveCell
                        chatTableView.beginUpdates()
                        row.downloadStatusIndicator.isHidden = true
                        row.downloadingIndicator.alpha = 1.0
                        chatTableView.endUpdates()
                    }else{
                        let row = chatTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FileSentCell
                        chatTableView.beginUpdates()
                        row.downloadStatusIndicator.isHidden = true
                        row.downloadingIndicator.alpha = 1.0
                        chatTableView.endUpdates()
                    }
                    downloadFileBackground(id: groupMsg.messageId!, fileName: groupMsg.fileOriginalName!, cellIndexPath: indexPath )

                    break
                }

            }
        }

        print(indexPath)
    }
}
```

For CellatRow

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let groupMsg = groupMsgList[indexPath.row]

    let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressed(_:)))

    groupId = groupMsg.groupId
    //MARK: MessageType is textmessage
    if (groupMsg.messageType == "message")
    {
        if (groupMsg.senderUserId != LoginStatusInfo.userId)
        {
            let cell : RecievedMessageCell = chatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recieve") as! RecievedMessageCell

            cell.name.text = groupMsg.senderDisplayName
            cell.message.text = groupMsg.message
            cell.time.text =  groupMsg.dateSent!
            //    cell.message.sizeToFit()
            cell.receiveMessageView.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.receiveMessageView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            let cell : SentMessageCell = chatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "send") as! SentMessageCell
            //    cell.sentMessageView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight,.bottomLeft], radius: 20)
            // cell.sentMessageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
            cell.sentMessageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.message.text = groupMsg.message
            cell.time.text =  groupMsg.dateSent!
            cell.messageStatus.isHidden = false
            cell.messageStatus.text = groupMsg.status
            //  cell.message.sizeToFit()
            cell.sentMessageView.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.sentMessageView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

            return cell

        }
    }
        //MARK: Message type is Banner
    else if (groupMsg.messageType == "banner") {
        let cell : BotBanner = chatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "botBanner") as! BotBanner
        hasBanner = true
        scrollToIndex = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
        //MARK: Message type is File
    else{
        if (groupMsg.senderUserId != LoginStatusInfo.userId)
        {
            //MARK: File Recived
            let fileNameString = groupMsg.fileOriginalName
            if(fileNameString != nil){
                let fileName: NSString = fileNameString! as NSString
                let extention = fileName.pathExtension.lowercased()
                let cell : FileRecieveCell = chatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fileRecieve") as! FileRecieveCell
                    let fileUrl = self.getImageURL(forFileName: fileNameString!)
                    if(fileUrl == nil){
                        cell.downloadStatusIndicator.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "fileDonwloadBlack")
                    }else{
                        cell.downloadStatusIndicator.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "downloadedBlack")
                    }
                    cell.downloadStatusIndicator.isHidden = false
                    cell.downloadingIndicator.alpha = 0.0
                    cell.receiveFileView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                    cell.name.text = groupMsg.senderDisplayName
                    cell.message.text = groupMsg.message
                    cell.time.text =  groupMsg.dateSent!
                    cell.fileIcon.image = returnImage(fileName:groupMsg.message!)
                    cell.receiveFileView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    cell.receiveFileView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
                    cell.receiveFileView.tag = indexPath.row
                    return cellname.text = groupMsg.senderDisplayName
                    cell.message.text = groupMsg.message
                    cell.time.text =  groupMsg.dateSent!
                    cell.fileIcon.image = returnImage(fileName:groupMsg.message!)
                    cell.receiveFileView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    cell.receiveFileView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
                    cell.receiveFileView.tag = indexPath.row
                    return cell
                }
        }
        else
        {
            let cell : FileSentCell = chatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fileSend") as! FileSentCell
                    let fileUrl = self.getImageURL(forFileName: fileNameString!)
                    if(fileUrl == nil){
                        cell.downloadStatusIndicator.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "fileDownloadWhite")
                    }else{
                        cell.downloadStatusIndicator.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "downloadedWhite")
                    }
                    cell.downloadStatusIndicator.isHidden = false
                    cell.downloadingIndicator.alpha = 0.0
                    cell.sendFileView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                    cell.name.text = groupMsg.senderDisplayName
                    cell.message.text = groupMsg.message
                    cell.time.text =  groupMsg.dateSent!
                    cell.fileStatus.text = groupMsg.status
                    cell.fileIcon.image = returnImage(fileName:groupMsg.message!)
                    cell.sendFileView.tag  = indexPath.row
                    cell.sendFileView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
                    cell.sendFileView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

                    return cell
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: see your screenshot, checkmark is appearing on right side of table view cell. If you want to show checkmark in circle then update circle image while tapping on tableview

Comment: please share your tableview cell for row & didselect method code

Comment: no the check mark shown on the view is added as an image

Comment: yes sharing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

My Mistake was i needed to add `cell.setSelectionStype = .default` in cellForAtRow

Answer (score 0):

Tableview use dequeueReusableCell , so you can

```
cell?.setSelected(true, animated: true)
```

When you scroll tableview , the same cell - reusable from a cell will is selected -> wrong.
In `GroupMessage` model add property: `isSelected` . and set

```
isSelected = true 
self.tableview.reloadrowatindexpath ....
```

when didselected

In `cellForRowAt indexPath`

```
If groupMsg.isSelected{
    cell?.setSelected(true, animated: true)
}else{
   cell?.setSelected(false, animated: true)
}
```

OR create a NSMutableArray - `selectedMessage` to hold message selected  didSelected add/remove groupmessage  in `selectedMessage` 
 In `cellForRowAt indexPath` check `selectedMessage` contains groupmessage  - setSelected = true or no